# customisation of Sign In portlet in hook

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-hook

I have developed hook for signIn portlet in  liferay 6.0 . I need to customize the labels of create account page. I need to customize following code

```
 <aui:input autoFocus="<%= windowState.equals(WindowState.MAXIMIZED) %>" model="<%= User.class %>" name="firstName" />
```

It is giving output as

[image]

I am not able to figure out from where/which file (Required) is coming. How can I customize the label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **required** comes from the User model, within th portal core. The `aui:input` taglib read the User model settings and manage the required validation. You cannot change this rule in the portla.
If you want to skip this behavior in jsp you have to write a standard input field manually.

For customize the label, the `aui:input` taglig has `label` attribute. (I hope i remember it right)

Comment: you remembered it correctly: `<aui:input ... label="..."/>`